# when a processor node's punctuate reaches looks up data in a state store, what partition is the data from?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When a stream-processor punctuate is called, and I pull all data from 
 a statestore via a call to KeyValueStateStore.all(), am I receiving all data from all partitions assigned to that kafka-streams task?  Or is it just data from one partition?

Answer (score 1):

When you called `KeyValueStateStore.all()` from `Punctuator` or `Processor` you get only data from particular Partition of changelog topic, that is assigned to Stream Task.
Same happens, when you modify: put, delete data it only applies to particular partition,

ex. If your input topic has 3 partition, than three instances of Processor will be created. 
If each of them will be putting into state store processing message using same key (ex. `k1`) all messages will endup in different partitions (although they have same key).

When you modify (put,delete) in `Processor` data in state store, you should use key from your message. If you won't do that it can lead to confusion describe above.